# Select PHP version for wordpress on Google cloud platform

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, google-cloud-platform, debian

i have been using Google Cloud Platform (GCP) for a while, and now im getting error in most of my wordpress sites, that i need to update my PHP

i used

```
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release

$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg # Download the signing key

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list' # Add Ondrej's repo to sources list.

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt-get install php7.3

To check the current version after the installation:

$ php -v
```

and it works

now

```
$ php -v
```

Shows this

```
    PHP 7.3.20-1+0~20200710.65+debian9~1.gbpc9cbeb (cli) (built: Jul 10 2020 07:22:47) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.20-1+0~20200710.65+debian9~1.gbpc9cbeb, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

But when i go to my wordpress it still show me

```
Running PHP version: 7.0.33-29+0~20200514.36+debian9~1.gbp126f6f
```

i tried multiple things and nothing is working, such as

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3

wp --info
```

and now it shows as

```
OS:     Linux 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1+deb9u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php7.3
PHP version:    7.3.20-1+0~20200710.65+debian9~1.gbpc9cbeb
php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:       /home/malriffaie
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
```

still same issue on wordpress, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've got two PHP versions installed: 7.0 and 7.3. You can check that:

```
$ php -v
  PHP 7.3.20...
$ which php
  /usr/bin/php
$ ls -l /usr/bin/php*
  lrwxrwxrwx 1      21 May 13 09:02 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php 
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 4389936 May 14 09:11 /usr/bin/php7.0 
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 4708288 Jul 10 07:22 /usr/bin/php7.3 
  lrwxrwxrwx 1      25 May 13 09:02 /usr/bin/php-cgi -> /etc/alternatives/php-cgi 
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 4283768 May 14 09:11 /usr/bin/php-cgi7.0
```

If the goal was to upgrade PHP, but not to use different versions in parallel, you should remove the previous PHP version as described here:

[Debian 9 - Upgrade To PHP 7.3](https://blog.programster.org/debian-9-upgrade-to-php-7-3)

Comment: thank you so much, this solved the issue that i was straggling with ^_^